# How to delete all the entities in Azure table?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I've been working on deleting all the rows in Azure table in java. Can I do it without querying it? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: delete and recreate?

Comment: no.. just delete all the rows.

Comment: Currently, we can't delete entries without specifying PK and RK from Azure table storage. I know that why you don't want to delete the table. If the table is deleted, we need to recreate the SAS for the table and dispatch to all the clients. If you know a pattern to calculate PK/RKs, you could use an algorithm to generate the PK/RK pair and delete the rows using [TableBatchOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablebatchoperation?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=azurestorage-8.1.3) which allow us executing multi operation at one time.

Comment: If I retrieve all the data, can I perform delete query on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I retrieve all the data, can I perform delete query on that?

If you just want to delete data, you just need to retrieve PKs and RKs. After retrieved all the data of PKs and RKs, you could perform the delete query for the entities one by one.

For complex delete query, for example, below query is not supported currently.

```
delete from tablename where PK = ''
```

I suggest you submit your idea on Azure feedback site which is used for features request.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage

Comment: Thank u for the reply. I tried to retrieve all the entites using 
  Iterable<DynamicTableEntity> entities = cloudTable.execute(new TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity>()); 

But it didn't work. Error was- The argument must not be null or an empty string

Comment: To retrieve all the entities, please use following code.  Iterable<DynamicTableEntity> entities = cloudTable.execute(TableQuery.from(DynamicTableEntity.class));

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to query the table, what you can do is to delete the table and recreate it.

Comment: I tried this one, and it was successful. But deleting a table may impact when inserting data at the same time. So I retrieved all the entities and performed delete batch operation.